# Trying to Override Wordpress CSS width for mega-menu submenu

Tags: css, wordpress

I created a mega-menu in wordpress by adding the mega-menu class.  I have two columns in the People mega-menu (site http://selfhost.kjk.com/).  In one column I have a list of linkable letters for a last name search.  I am trying to get this list to be horizontal and wrap.  In inspect mode, I just need to change the width of these items to 10%.  However, it keeps ignoring my !important and reverting to 100% width.  Here is my code:  (the background-color works)

```
#top-menu .sub-menu .az-submenu{
background-color:#000;
width:10% !important;
}
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: I built the menu in the Wordpress editor.  The submenu is a taxonomy of letters (referring to last name in custom post types).  I added the class .az-submenu to each of the sub-menu items that are letters.  I've just been using inspect mode to see what html was used.  The css I show above is working on background color, but won't change the width.

Comment: I changed it to max-width:10% !important and it worked - thanks for your efforts